# Storing long long in a char array without truncating

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I have an array of elements of type `uint8_t` stored in an array, and need to basically concatenate them, and generate a string form of the result.
Is there a way to store `long long` in a char array without truncating? in other words, how can you store 64-bits in a char array?
In the following example, `abacce` to `"abacce"`

```
void concat(uint8_t *arr, int size) {
   unsigned long long val=0;
   for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      val <<= 8;
      val |= arr[i];
   }
   printf ("%x\n", val);  // abacce -- perfect!
   
   // now I need to convert this to a char array since I need to pass this to a function that takes in a char array!!  -- below is my failed attempt...

   char arr[10];
   sprintf(arr, "%x", val); // char = 8 bytes so it truncates the first byte only!
}

int main(void) {
   uint8_t arr[] = {0xab, 0xac, 0xce};
   concat(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
}
```

Okay someone mentioned in the comments that `%llx` would store the hexa representation of the long long unsigned and in the online IDE, it seems to work, however when I tried the following in eclipse, I get `lx`:

```
void concat(uint8_t *arr, int size, char *str) {
       unsigned long long val=0;
       for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
          val <<= 8;
          val |= arr[i];
       }
      sprintf(str, "%llx", var); // str has "lx" instead of "0x30abcdababcd"
      return val;
}
int main(void) {
   char str[20] = {0};
   uint8_t arr[] = {0x30, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xab, 0xab, 0xcd};
   long long unsigned var = concat(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0], str);
}
```

Comment: `printf` and `sprintf` (which I assume you meant, I don't know what `sprint` is) with `%x` should give you the same thing. You have a shadowed variable with `arr` though so I'm not sure what your actual intent is.

Comment: Just want to store `abacce` which is stored in `val` into a string form in `arr`

Comment: Which `arr`? The one you passed in or the one you declared later in the function? I have to assume this isn't your real code since that shouldn't compile, but let's say you remove the second declaration and try to put more than 3 characters into the `arr` variable that's passed in. It won't fit.

Comment: This works: https://ideone.com/xHjsaQ

Comment: the result is stored in `arr` which is defined inside `concat()`

Comment: i'm not sure if I get your point about bytes not fitting in.`abacce` has 3 bytes in total which we are storing in a char array of size 10

Comment: You have a variable named `arr` that is passed in and then you try to declare it again inside the function. If that compiles for you, especially with the missing `)` in main then you have a much more lenient compiler than I do.

Comment: oh right. i should name it differently for sure.

Comment: regarding the size, I assume you randomly picked 64 bytes....

Comment: also, seems like `%llx` isn't quite working on my end...

Comment: please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which shows the unexpected truncation

Comment: posted @M.M....

Comment: @MKD -- well, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means something we can copy, paste, compile and verify your results to help you with your question.

Comment: Like I said, I can only see this issue in eclipse IDE

Comment: there's no minimal example yet, and you seem to be talking about two different problems, "output being truncated", and seeing "lx"

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues that should be jumping out of the IDE at you:

```
  sprintf(str, "%llx", var);
```

`var` is not decalred. You mean `val`.

Next, you have an incomplete expression due to an unmatched `'('` in:

```
    sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0], str);
```

Better as `sizeof arr/ sizeof arr[0]`.

Next, you attempt to assign the return of a function of type `void` in the line with the problem above:

```
long long unsigned var = concat(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0], str);
```

Your declaration of `concat()` is:

```
void concat(...
```

You cannot return a `long long unsigned` from `void`. What you want is:

```
unsigned long long concat(uint8_t *arr, int size, char *str)
{
    unsigned long long val=0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        val <<= 8;
        val |= arr[i];
    }
    sprintf(str, "%llx", val); // str has "lx" instead of "0x30abcdababcd"
    return val;
}
```

Now your code works reasonably well. Add a `printf` at the end of `main()` to verify the value of `var` and `str`, e.g.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[20] = {0};
    uint8_t arr[] = {0x30, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xab, 0xab, 0xcd};
    long long unsigned var = concat(arr, sizeof arr /sizeof arr[0], str);
    printf ("%llx   %s\n", var, str);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/concatuint8
30abcdababcd   30abcdababcd
```

Your compiler should be giving you the line where each of the errors above occurred. If not there is something very wrong with the IDE you are using or how you have it configured. Simply compiling from the command line in Linux or Windows takes less than a second and will disclose all issues with **warnings enabled** (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS)

Look things over and let me know if you have more questions.

**Edit 2 Regarding STM32 F401 Microcontroller**

After further discussion, you are working with the [STM32 F401](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f401.html) microcontroller. On these, or any, microcontroller where you are compiling and running code on "bare metal" without an operating system, you are working in what is called a *freestanding environment* [C11 Standard - 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1). The fact that you are using `gcc-eabi` instead of `gcc-none-eabi` suggests you are targeting some kind of OS on your microcontroller. It too may effect what is available.

The catch is that much of what you have to work with will be *implementation defined* and doesn't necessarily comport with the C standard. This is especially true for those arm boards that have several different modes (targets) that can be compiled and linked. Here you have both a `thumb` mode and `arm` mode that effect what register sizes are used and consequently what the integer sizes available are. While the Cortex-M4 process will support the `ll`, `ull` and `llu` length modifiers, they may not be available in all compiler and linker modes [ARM Compiler Toolchain - long long](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Ciabcebf.html)

You will need to double-check your compiler options and the IDE options to make sure you are targeting a build that will support `long long` as 64-bit and make the `ll` or `ull` or `llu` modifiers available. This will come from the OS you are using `Free RTOS`? and the compiler documentation. The gcc [ARM Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) address the compiler options, but whether you are working on "bare metal" or targeting some type of operating system running on your board will also make a difference.

This is the challenge of working with microcontrollers and embedded systems. In addition to learning C, you have an equal learning curve for the specific hardware itself. You will need to get your arms around the OS, if any, you are targeting along with the Cortex-M4 processor options. I would suggest nailing down the exact OS you are using, if any, and then re-ask in a separate narrowly tailored question similar to "Why is the `%llx` modifier for `printf` not working on a STM32 F401EE board with Cortex M4 Processor". Use the ARM tag and look for any specific for STM32 board. That will get the question defined at a level that will invite those with that specific knowledge to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I should’ve rechecked my code before posting here. But really I don’t see any errors. My main concern is getting “lx” instead of the intended string. I suspect it has to do with %llx specifier

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The *length modifiers* `l` for `long` and `ll` for `long long` are standard, (See [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p6)) but some IDEs (Eclipse is notorious for quirks) may not flag or accept certain syntax. Is this current Eclipse or an older version)?

Comment: On not seeing `error`s, I'm not sure what to tell you. Your code as posted has 5-errors, 2-warnings and 2-notes. If Eclipse isn't showing the errors on compile, you must not have the output window configured so it appears and presents the error. Each of the 5-error are required to generate a diagnostic -- so the compiler output of the errors is there -- it may not be shown -- but it is there.

Comment: No I meant I should’ve checked my code before posting. The things that I missed here weren’t in my actual code so I don’t get errors that you mentioned. Regarding the compiler, I’m using gcc arm eabi tool hain which I believe uses gnu compiler

Comment: Yes you are correct about gcc-arm-eabi being a GNU compiler. So you are compiling for an embedded system or microcontroller such as an Arduino or TI MSP, etc... There can be limitations from the hardware itself that are coming into play. Please post the maker and model of what you are compiling for so I can look up the types supported. If you are compiling for a *freestanding environment* (No OS), then most of what it supports will be *Implementation Defined* and not from the C standard necessarily.

Comment: STM32F401EE arm based MCU

Comment: Give me a sec to check and I'll drop a comment or edit back.

Comment: Appreciate it really

Comment: I found your [STM32 F401](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f401.html) which uses a Cortex-4M processor. The `ll` or `ull` or `llu` modifiers for `long long` are supported [ARM Compiler Toolchain - long long](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/Ciabcebf.html) (same info in current 675 page .pdf). Now that said, you may have compiler or **linker** options needed to put the processor in a mode that can use the `long long` type. I don't have the reference, but many microcontroller have a 16-bit thumb mode that will not support 64-bit integers.

Comment: You will need to find your linker reference and ensure you are providing the correct target for enabling full 64-bit integers in your code. I suspect you currently have the compiler configured to output the basic 16-bit version where you need to configure it to compile and link where the 64-bit integer support is enabled. It will take a little more google foo to find out what that is for your STM32 F401 -- virtually all chips will have different targets and options. If this is part of a course, check the course material closely for any compiler/linker mode information.

Comment: Here are the gcc arm `-m` options, check that `-mthumb` isn't enable and you are compiling in arm mode [3.19.5 ARM Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -m options do not matter here. He needs to change the spec file to use libc instead of nanolib to have a full printf implementation. But I will not advice it as eventually it will consume plenty of FLASH memory.

Comment: Thank you. I have worked with the TI Microcontrollers and the Pi, but did not have to change which lib (aside from though compile/link options -- and I don't use Eclipse). I knew sooner or later someone familiar with this microcontroller and Eclipse would drop by. This is an area where you have to learn the microcontroller just as you have to learn C.